# WPF GroupBox control template

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a code where I have groupbox and which have checkbox in wrap panel which actually wrap unwrap the groupbox  and is is a requirement so working fine.
But checkbox inside border  also wrap my groupbox on uncheck which I don't want. 
Can you please suggest how can I create a functionality where checkbox inside border doesn't wrap my groupbox.

```
    <StackPanel.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="GroupBox" x:Key="groupBoxStyle">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="CheckBox.Unchecked">
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height" Duration="0:0:.2"  To="30" />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="CheckBox.Checked">
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height" Duration="0:0:.2" />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </StackPanel.Resources>
    <GroupBox Margin="8,0" Height="150" BorderBrush="Transparent" Style="{StaticResource groupBoxStyle}">
        <GroupBox.Header>
            <WrapPanel >
                <CheckBox IsChecked="True" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                <Label Content="Volatility" Background="#00000000" Foreground="#FF0033FF" FontWeight="Bold" />
            </WrapPanel>
        </GroupBox.Header>
        <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
            <UniformGrid Columns="2">
                <Label Content="Spots"></Label>
                <TextBox AcceptsReturn="False" AcceptsTab="True" AllowDrop="True" IsTabStop="True" />
                <Label Content="Hist. references" />
                <TextBox AcceptsReturn="False" AcceptsTab="True" AllowDrop="True" IsTabStop="True" />
                <Label Content="Tenors" />
                <TextBox AcceptsReturn="False" AcceptsTab="True" AllowDrop="True" IsTabStop="True" />
                <Label Content="(5) Is there Value Plan? Yes/No" Margin="0,0,-42,0"  />
                <CheckBox Margin="0,5,0,0" Name="chkISvalue" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="84" Style="{x:Null}"  Checked="chkISvalue_Checked" Unchecked="chkISvalue_Unchecked" />
            </UniformGrid>
        </Border>
    </GroupBox>
</StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set SourceName in EventTrigger, so it applies only to correct CheckBox. You will also need to move EventTrigger from style to Triggers of GroupBox itself so you can use CheckBox name.
Full example:

```
<StackPanel>    
<GroupBox Margin="8,0" Height="150" BorderBrush="Transparent" Style="{StaticResource groupBoxStyle}">
  <GroupBox.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="CheckBox.Unchecked" SourceName="WrappingCheckBox">
      <BeginStoryboard>
        <Storyboard>
          <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height" Duration="0:0:.2"  To="30" />
        </Storyboard>
      </BeginStoryboard>
    </EventTrigger>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="CheckBox.Checked">
      <BeginStoryboard>
        <Storyboard>
          <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height" Duration="0:0:.2" />
        </Storyboard>
      </BeginStoryboard>
    </EventTrigger>
  </GroupBox.Triggers>
  <GroupBox.Header>
    <WrapPanel >
      <CheckBox Name="WrappingCheckBox" IsChecked="True" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
      <Label Content="Volatility" Background="#00000000" Foreground="#FF0033FF" FontWeight="Bold" />
    </WrapPanel>
  </GroupBox.Header>
  <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
    <UniformGrid Columns="2">
      <Label Content="Spots"></Label>
      <TextBox AcceptsReturn="False" AcceptsTab="True" AllowDrop="True" IsTabStop="True" />
      <Label Content="Hist. references" />
      <TextBox AcceptsReturn="False" AcceptsTab="True" AllowDrop="True" IsTabStop="True" />
      <Label Content="Tenors" />
      <TextBox AcceptsReturn="False" AcceptsTab="True" AllowDrop="True" IsTabStop="True" />
      <Label Content="(5) Is there Value Plan? Yes/No" Margin="0,0,-42,0"  />
      <CheckBox Margin="0,5,0,0" Name="chkISvalue" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="84" Style="{x:Null}" />
    </UniformGrid>
  </Border>
</GroupBox>
```